# Grouping in new variable based on a time frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df with two columns, one with dates, one with values. I want to graph these values with gglot, using geom_col.

However, there were 'interventions' in the time that passed, which affected the values. I want to highlight these interventions by having the bars change colour after a certain date.

One way to do this is to create a new column ('Change') with factor variables like TF1, TF2, TF2 and set these in the aes-section. So what I'm looking for is a piece of code that works like:

- If the date is between A and B, `df$Change` is TF1
- If the date is between C and D, `df$Change` is TF2
- If date is between E and F, `df$Change` is TF3

What I tried so far is:

```
QASTART = as.Date('2020-03-16')
df <- df %>% mutate(Change = Datum >= QASTART)
```

But it's only giving me two categories to work with. I want at least three or potentially more.

This is the head of my df:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17595, 17602, 17609, 17616, 
17623, 17630), class = "Date"), UPV = c(756L, 696L, 704L, 661L, 
713L, 649L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Comment: `case_when` can probably help. Something like `mutate(Change = case_when(between(Datum, A, B) ~ "TF1", ...)) `

Comment: This works for one, but with a second one, R throws a fit:

```> df %>% mutate(Change = case_when( between ( Datum, A, B) ~ "TF1"), between(Datum, C, D) ~ "TF2" )```  

``Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
i Input `..2` is `between(Datum, C, D) ~ "TF2"`.````

Comment: you have an extra bracket after tf1

Answer (score 0):

The case_when-solution that was proposed did the trick for me. There are probably more elegant solutions than this, but this is what I did.

```
A = as.Date('2018-03-05')
B = as.Date('2020-03-15')
C = as.Date('2020-03-16')
D = as.Date('2020-07-12')
E = as.Date('2020-07-13')
G = as.Date('2020-08-31')

df <- df %>% mutate(Change = case_when( between ( Datum, A, B) ~ "TF1", between(Datum, C, D) ~ "TF2", between(Datum, E, G) ~ "TF3" )) 

ggplot(df, aes(Datum, UPV, col=Change))+geom_col()
```